# Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 4 by reference in

Tags: php, magento

[LokoSphere - Goggle Straps](https://www.lokosphere.com/goggle-straps) - This is where I am getting the error. Same theme/template being used on separate stores without this error

```
<h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(),'name'),$trimSize,'...','',true); ?></a></h2>
```

This is the code shown on line 272

I am at a loss of what to do

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the 4th argument is expected to be a reference to a variable.

You may once give a look to the arguments passed to the method truncate()

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method definition of `truncate()`:

```
public function truncate($string, $length = 80, $etc = '...', &$remainder = '', $breakWords = true)`
```

You will notice that the fourth argument is `&$reminder = ''` which means that it is passed by reference and has a default value of empty string. You [cannot pass a literal by reference at runtime](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). In your case, you are just passing the default values of the method anyway, so you can just omit the last three arguments like this:

```
Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($_product->getName(), $trimSize)
```